# Order of growth: substitution of monotonically increasing functions

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation, mathematical-foundations

One strategy for ordering the growth of functions involves substitutions when comparing functions using the limit as $n$ goes to infinity comparing two equations using the following rule.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
0, & f(n) \in O(g(n))  \\\
\infty, & f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))  \\\
c\neq 0, & f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))  \end{array} \right.
$$

Using a substitution was a new strategy to me, and it was explicitly used with logarithms because they are [monotonically increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). For example:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{lg(n)^{lg(n)}}{2^{lg(n)}} = \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k^k}{2^k}
$$

Obviously, this is a much easier problem to solve, and is much easier to prove in this form. The only two cases this was useful on the assignment I was working on was with logarithms, as in the case above, and [iterated logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).

Are there other useful substitutions like this, or is there a broader implication of these monotonically increasing functions outside the realm of comparing order of growth? A big pet peeve is learning about a math concept in practice before in principle, because I don't feel like I understand the big picture. What realm of mathematics does this fall into?

Comment: It's not important that logarithm is an increasing function. What we need is that if $k = \lg n$ then $n\to\infty$ iff $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes, good point. It only matters that $k$ is increasing because $n$ is increasing. But would its monotonic nature still be important?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: No, monotonicity is nearly irrelevant. You can replace $\lg n$ by $\max_{k<n} {\lg k}$ and the behaviour at the limit is invariant. This you can do for almost any function